# (Databricks) - ERROR: canceling statement due to conflict with recovery

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have a schedule job that appeared an error today:

[Error on Databricks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckwiV.png)

**org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: canceling statement due to conflict with recovery**

There's a way to solve this on Databricks? How? Thanks!!

Tried to find something on the configs, but didn't have success.

Answer (score 0):

If you are querying a secondary installation (replica) and there are conflicting changes that need to be replayed from the primary there are two options:

1. Delay replaying the changes (replication will fall further behind)
2. Cancel the running query that conflicts with the changes

PostgreSQL will do 1 until it hits a configured timeout and then do 2 so your replication doesn't fall too far behind.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/hot-standby.html#HOT-STANDBY-CONFLICT